# Deleting elements from list using another list

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to delete the elements from list1 that are in list1

```
    package listCollection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;



public class Arry2List {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] s = {"INDIA" ,"JAPAN","THAILAND","MALAYSIA"};
        ArrayList<String> list1= new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] s1 = {"THAILAND","MALAYSIA"};
        ArrayList<String> list2= new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String temp : s)
        {
            list1.add(temp);
        }
        for(String temp : s1)
        {
            list2.add(temp);
        }


        //removing elements from list1 that are in list2


        System.out.println("In list1 **************");
        for (String t : list1)
        {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        System.out.println("In list2 **************");
        for (String t1 : list2)
        {
            System.out.println(t1);
        }
        //editlist(list1,list2);
        Iterator<String> i=list1.iterator();

          while( i.hasNext() )
          {
               if ( list2.contains( i.hasNext() ) )
               {
                   i.remove();
               }

          }
        System.out.println("In list1 again **************");

        for(int i1 =0;i1<list1.size();i1++)
        {
            System.out.println(list1.get(i1));
        }


    }




    }
```

Output should be INDIA,JAPAN.
List1 should contain only those elements which are not in the list2.

I am a beginner to Core Java and trying to learn collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop that checks the element using `List.contains()`, you're passing a boolean (`i.hasNext()` returns whether the iterator has more elements) instead of the element. This causes the loop to run infinitely because you never call `Iterator.next()` to get the next element. You should use:

```
if (list2.contains(i.next())) {
```

instead of

```
if (list2.contains(i.hasNext())) {
```

It's better practice to also save the next element in a variable for re-usability:

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
    String element = i.next();
    if (list2.contains(element)) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am figuring out how to close the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in method to do that:

```
list1.removeAll(list2)
```

[EDIT]

You can create the lists easier using Arrays.asList:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("INDIA", "JAPAN", "THAILAND", "MALAYSIA"));
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("THAILAND", "MALAYSIA");
list1.removeAll(list2);
```

[EDIT2]

The Arrays.asList produces unmodifiable list, so we have to use it to initialize a modifiable one.

[EDIT3]

Your code doesn't work because you don't advance the iterator. `i.hasNext()` only checks if there is a next element. It returns `true` or `false`, not the element itself. Here is how to fix this:

```
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        if (list2.contains(i.next())) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
```

You can also iterate over the `list2` elements and remove them from `list1`:

```
    for (String el : list2) {
        list1.remove(el);
    }
```

Comment: Cool it worked.But why my code is running indefinitenly.I am trying to learn 
various methods

Comment: Ok. check EDIT3... :)

Comment: Thanks.Will upvote when i get the required reputation